# How can I run python script from Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins-pipeline

How can I run python script from Jenkins declarative pipeline?
The machine is Windows and I already have python 2.7 installed on it.    I tried several ways:

```
    def return_val = bat(script: 'C:\\aaa.py', returnStdout: true)
    python  C:\\aaa.py
    python.exe  C:\\aaa.py
    python returnStatus: true, script: 'C:\\aaa.py'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a windows instance to try this on, but I think your first line is on the right track.

The problem is that you're trying to run the python file directly. According to [pythoncentral](https://www.pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/) you should run python.exe and pass your .py file as an argument.

On the command line you'd do the following:

```
C:\path\to\python.exe C:\\aaa.py
```

Which we can put into your first line to get:

```
def return_val = bat(script: 'C:\path\to\python.exe C:\\aaa.py', returnStdout: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Creating your first Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/) and  [Microsoft PowerShell Support for Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/07/26/powershell-pipeline/) should answer your question as below,

```
    pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'python:3.5.1' } }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                powershell 'python --version'
            }
        }
     }
   }
```